# Perform row multiplication in data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, operation

I want to perform the following operation in pandas, I wouldn't like to transform my Dataframe in array to perform.

```
date      A      B     C     D     E    ...
date1     0,03  0,02  0,01   0,01 0,234
date2     0,03  0,02  0,01   0,01 0,234
date3     0,03  0,02  0,01   0,01 0,234
date4     0,03  0,02  0,01   0,01 0,234
```

the numbers are not the same and have lots of decimal values. 
 I want to create in another data frame the following :

```
date      value      
date1     (1+0,03)*(1+0,02)*(1+0,01)*(1+0,01)*(1+0,234)
date2     (1+0,03)*(1+0,02)*(1+0,01)*(1+0,01)*(1+0,234)
date3     (1+0,03)*(1+0,02)*(1+0,01)*(1+0,01)*(1+0,234)
date4     (1+0,03)*(1+0,02)*(1+0,01)*(1+0,01)*(1+0,234)
```

there are cells where the value is null, I want to skip those values. 
I would show what I have been trying, but what I did was transform to array and perform the operation, I loose my data and can't skip null values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create index by dates if necessary by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), then add `1` for each value and use [`DataFrame.prod`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.prod.html):

```
#if not numeric values replace , and convert to floats
#df = df.replace(',','.', regex=True)
df1 = df.set_index('date').astype(float).add(1).prod(axis=1).reset_index(name='value')
print (df1)
    date     value
0  date1  1.322499
1  date2  1.322499
2  date3  1.322499
3  date4  1.322499
```

Test with missing value:

```
print (df)
    date     A     B     C     D      E
0  date1  0,03  0,02  0,01  0,01    NaN
1  date2  0,03  0,02  0,01  0,01  0,234
2  date3  0,03  0,02  0,01  0,01  0,234
3  date4  0,03  0,02  0,01  0,01  0,234

df = df.replace(',','.', regex=True)

print (df.set_index('date').astype(float).add(1))
          A     B     C     D      E
date                                
date1  1.03  1.02  1.01  1.01    NaN
date2  1.03  1.02  1.01  1.01  1.234
date3  1.03  1.02  1.01  1.01  1.234
date4  1.03  1.02  1.01  1.01  1.234

df1 = df.set_index('date').astype(float).add(1).prod(axis=1).reset_index(name='value')
print (df1)
    date     value
0  date1  1.071717
1  date2  1.322499
2  date3  1.322499
3  date4  1.322499
```